# Get parent url parameter

Tags: angular

I have this routing

```
import { ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './app.child-component';
import { Child2Component } from './child2-component';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'AppComponent',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: ':lang',
        children:
        [
            {
                path: '',
                component: ChildComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'Child2Component',
                component: Child2Component
            }
        ]
    }
];

export const appRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

I want to get that lang parameter from my function which looks:

```
translateThis(lang: any) {

    // this line works fine
    this.translate.use(lang);

    // this doesn't
    this.sub = this.route.parent.queryParams.subscribe(
    (param: any) => {
        let lang = param['lang'];
        console.log(param);
        console.log(userId);
    });

}
```

but it stops working as soon i uncomment this.sub code (whole 6 lines). without that it works ok

```
translateThis(lang: any) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
}
```

How can I get that lang value? I tried `params` as well instead of queryParams but result is same

Comment: So it basically works? What are the 6 lines exactly that break it when you remove them?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it translates my website without any problem. Then I want to change url too. that's why i need to get that lang parameter (for example it's 'eng') and then change to desired parameter (for example 'fr')

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what actually is working and what is not working.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer not working this.sub

Comment: How does the URL look like with the query parameters.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/en/Child2Component and i want to get en

Comment: @gsiradze Your code is very confusing, can't figure out what method translateThis(lang) should do... This line is also very unclear: let userId = param['lang']; Does this URL path parameter 'lang' represents userId or language?

Comment: That's not a query parameter. You have to use `this.route.parent.params.subscribe(`

Comment: @MarinRelatic I've edited. Thanks for watching I'm little confused now

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it does same thing

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
translateThis() {
  // Subscribe to router params observable
  this.sub= this.route.parent.params.subscribe(
    param => {
      let lang = param['lang'];
      console.log(lang);
      // Call method or something
      this.translate.use(lang);
  });
}
```

Here's a full example of what I believe you need. Note that subscribtion to route params should be unsubscribed manually

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private sub;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    // Subscribe to router params observable
    this.sub= this.route.parent.params.subscribe(
      param => {
        let lang = param['lang'];
        console.log(lang);
        // Call method or something
        this.translateThis(lang);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // Unsubscribe from router params observable
    this.sub.unsubscribe();

  }

  translateThis(lang: any) {
    // Do your thing here
    // this.translate.use(lang);
  }
}
```

Comment: now I'm getting `Error: Bootstrap at least one component before injecting Router`